# Prevent Horrendously Wide NSBrowserCell Tool Tips

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbrowser

I am setting my `NSBrowser` matrix cells' tool tips with the below code:

```
- (void) browser:(NSBrowser *)sender willDisplayCell:(id)cell atRow:(int)row column:(int)column  {  
    NSMatrix *matrix = [sender matrixInColumn:column];
    NSLog(@"'%@'", [cell title]);
    [matrix setToolTip:[cell title] forCell:[matrix cellAtRow:row column:column]];    
}
```

This results in wonderful tool tips, most of the time.

When hovering some cells, however, the tool tip expands to a grotesque width, transforming an otherwise delightful experience into one that is as hideous as it is confusing. The screenshot below shows this horrible behaviour.

[image: Wide load]

The output for the cell triggering the heinous tool tip pictured above is:

```
'gnome-1.1-tb-linux.jar'
```

What could be causing these seemingly random atrocities - am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What version of OS X are you seeing this on?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan 10.7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that worked for me in this case was to implement `- (NSRect)expansionFrameWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)view` in my `NSBrowserCell` subclass as below:

```
- (NSRect)expansionFrameWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)view {
    NSSize size = [self.tooltipText sizeWithAttributes:@{
                       NSFontAttributeName: [NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSize]]
                   }];
    // Expansion frame displays below and indented to the right in relation to the cellFrame
    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(cellFrame.origin.x + 10, cellFrame.origin.y + size.height, size.width, size.height);
    return rect;
}
```